# How do i choose 4G LTE on Project Tango GSM or CDMA?

Tags: google-project-tango

I have the sim cards but can someone tell me what kind of service i should be getting either GSM or CDMA. And what steps i should take in regards to APN settings.

Answer (score 1):

Project Tango support GSM not CDMA. 
Not specific setting needed for APN
just following the setting from the sim.